Need tags from the images in aks
I have an images list like this
testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/reloader:v1.0.51
testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-id:19900909.1
testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-license:19900909.1
testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-finalsync:19900906.2
testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-tubelas:19900909.1
mcr.microsoft.com/aks/ip-masq-agent-v2:v0.1.11
mcr.microsoft.com/oss/kubernetes/kube-proxy:v1.30.3

and looking for an output with powershell command to only with the tags with specific name and discard remaining
ip-id
19900909.1
ip-license
19900906.2
ip-finalsync
19900906.2
ip-tubelas
19900909.1

Need output in same row
ip-id 19900909.1
ip-license 19900906.2
ip-finalsync 19900906.2
ip-tubelas 19900909.1

after the multiple values got list as below
Input
ip-id 19900909.1
ip-license 19900906.2
ip-finalsync 19900906.2
ip-tubelas 19900909.1
ip-id 19900809.1
ip-license 19900905.2
ip-finalsync 19900606.2
ip-tubelas 19900709.1
ip-id 19900509.1
ip-license 19900406.2
ip-finalsync 19900306.2
ip-tubelas 19900309.1

Expecting as below
ip-id = "19900909.1","19900809.1", "19900509.1"
ip-license = "19900906.2", "19900905.2", "19900406.2"
ip-finalsync = "19900306.2", "19900906.2", "19900606.2"
ip-tubelas =  ".,.,."


The .Remove method in PowerShell doesn't work the way you're attempting to use it, as it expects a single string, and you're trying to use it on an array.
To filter out the specific tags and names and discard the numbers at the beginning of the strings, you can use a combination of -replace to remove the numbers and Select-String or Where-Object to filter specific names.
use this script
# The list of image tags from the previous command
$imageTags = @(
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/reloader:v1.0.51",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-id:19900909.1",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-license:19900909.1",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-finalsync:19900906.2",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-tubelas:19900909.1",
    "mcr.microsoft.com/aks/ip-masq-agent-v2:v0.1.11",
    "mcr.microsoft.com/oss/kubernetes/kube-proxy:v1.30.3"
)

# Filter the image tags with "ip-" in the name and extract the tags
$filteredTags = $imageTags | Where-Object {
    # Filter lines containing "ip-"
    $_ -like "*ip-*"
} | ForEach-Object {
    # Extract the image name and version
    $nameVersion = $_ -split '[:/]'
    # Output the image name and version
    $nameVersion[2], $nameVersion[3]
}

# Output the filtered tags
$filteredTags



Example-
Deploy your images

Check the pods

Run the script I shared above

update for your follow up question-
To format the output of your PowerShell script so that the image name and version appear on the same line use the below script-
edited script-
# The list of image tags from the previous command
$imageTags = @(
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/reloader:v1.0.51",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-id:19900909.1",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-license:19900909.1",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-finalsync:19900906.2",
    "testcontainersgw.azurecr.io/tef/ip-tubelas:19900909.1",
    "mcr.microsoft.com/aks/ip-masq-agent-v2:v0.1.11",
    "mcr.microsoft.com/oss/kubernetes/kube-proxy:v1.30.3"
)

# Filter the image tags with "ip-" in the name and extract the tags
$filteredTags = $imageTags | Where-Object {
    # Filter lines containing "ip-"
    $_ -like "*ip-*"
} | ForEach-Object {
    # Extract the image name and version
    $nameVersion = $_ -split '[:/]'
    # Output the image name and version in one line
    "$($nameVersion[2]) $($nameVersion[3])"
}

# Output the formatted tags
$filteredTags


output using the previous script vs output using this edited one.


How I can make an output as
ip-id 19900909.1
ip-license 19900906.2
ip-finalsync 19900906.2
ip-tubelas 19900909.1


updated the answer with your follow up requirement.

after the list I got multiple lists and want to store in a single variable is it possible
ip-id 19900909.1
ip-license 19900906.2
ip-finalsync 19900906.2
ip-tubelas 19900909.1
ip-id 19900809.1
ip-license 19900905.2
ip-finalsync 19900606.2
ip-tubelas 19900709.1
ip-id 19900509.1
ip-license 19900406.2
ip-finalsync 19900306.2
ip-tubelas 19900309.1
expecting to store as ip-id = "19900909.1","19900809.1", "19900509.1"
ip-license = "19900906.2", "19900905.2", "19900406.2"
ip-finalsync = "19900306.2", "19900906.2", "19900606.2"
ip-tubelas =  ".,.,."

I have updated with my last requirement
